# DXL error while running script via batch mode. (Stack Underflow)

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a piece of .dxl code that opens a module and modifies some attributes.The codes works perfectly in the Doors DXL Editor, no errors what so ever ,but when I try to execute the code via doors batch file mode I get a pesky crash dump with the following error:
The command that I run from the cmd:

```
doors -d 36677@SERVER-ADDRESS -u my_username -P my_password -b "D:\my_script.dxl" -maxMemory 9999
```

and the error:

```
-R-E- DXL: <Line:0> Stack Underflow
DOORS: **** Translating a structured exception ****
DOORS: Version 9.3.0.6, build number 93576, built on Nov 29 2011 22:40:09.
DOORS: Microsoft Enterprise Edition (build 9200), 64-bit
DOORS: DOORS: 43 percent of memory is in use.
DOORS: There are 2097151 total Kbytes of physical memory.
DOORS: There are 2097151 free Kbytes of physical memory.
DOORS: There are 4194303 total Kbytes of paging file.
DOORS: There are 4194303 free Kbytes of paging file.
DOORS: There are 1fff80 total Kbytes of virtual memory.
DOORS: There are 1aab84 free Kbytes of virtual memory.

DOORS: argv[0]: doors
DOORS: argv[1]: -d
DOORS: argv[2]: 36677@SERVER-ADDRESS
DOORS: argv[3]: -u
DOORS: argv[4]: my_username
DOORS: argv[5]: -P
DOORS: argv[6]: my_password
DOORS: argv[7]: -b
DOORS: argv[8]: D:\my_script.dxl
DOORS: argv[9]: -maxMemory
DOORS: argv[10]: 9999
DOORS: Exception timestamp: 19/02/2019 at 13:37:19
DOORS: doors.exe caused an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in module doors.exe at 0023:00826126
DOORS: 0023:00826126 (0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000) doors.exe
DOORS: **** end of event ****
DOORS: Writing exception details...
DOORS: Exception details have been written to: d:\temp\DOORS-93576-2019_02_19-13_37_19-9808-5268.dmp

Press return to exit DOORS.
```

I guess that the error is because of memory allocation, but I am lost on this one. Is there any memory limit imposed when running from the batch mode? The thing is that it says that **"Doors: 43 percent of memory in use"** and in task-manager when running the code/opening the module in case it takes about 120 MB of RAM.

I can provide the crash dump as well if requested.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the code thats running?

Some dxl commands don't work correctly in batch mode compared to the regular environment, mostly ones that have to do with views / window configuration.

Comment: I will provide one tomorrow . The main code is simple enough : `like Module m = edit("/ModulePathGoeshere", false,true,false)`

Answer (score 0):

Summary:
Bregman is correct, post the DXL, or at least the 1st few lines.  Yes, batch mode disallows some commands.
I say Get rid of the -maxMemory command line switch.

Discussion:
First off, that dump is useful only for the hard-core IBM nerds who debug the doors.exe itself.  In all the 10s of 1000s of errors I've had I've never used it to debug DXL; nor have I seen a post that used it. (However, the "arg" list has been useful sometimes).  Don't bother posting it.  You were quite correct to stub out the server name, user name, and password.

The DXL window error is the important one, and I see you gave us that:
-R-E- DXL:  Stack Underflow
Usually there is some trace information also.

I am unfamiliar with that "-maxMemory 9999" command line switch.  My notes have a question mark about it which means Mr MM the expert didn't know what it does, if anything.  I certainly do not.

I strongly suspect that is your problem.  Whatever it does, you don't need it, remove it.  The fact that you get an error at line zero (which appears to have the meaning of "after interpreting but before line 1 was executed) is consistent with running out of memory during initialization.  Understand that the 1st line in your DXL is line #1. not line #0.

If you insist on keeping it: If it behaves as it seems, My guess the number is "bytes", and 9999 is hopelessly small, try 2 gig: 2000000000, or 4gig.  I'm supposing the default is 4gig now anyway, and that switch is to reduce memory hog; but I don't know how that could be useful at all.

I am very curious where you got it from.

-Louie

Answer (score 0):

The execution was crashing due to excess memory usages, which was happening due to the script opening the modules in the saved view(lot of data), hence change it to read the standard view only and it works fine:

```
m = read(modName,false)
```

To:

```
m = read(modName,false,true)
```